# Why the remainder of a float divided by a bigger integer than itself returns the float itself?

Tags: ruby, math, irb

I'm pretty new to programming concept totally I am learning ruby at the moment!

I was playing a bit around with `irb` and saw the remainder of a floating point divided by an integer bigger than itself return the float itself.
for example `2.5 % 5` returned `2.5`.

I was expecting the result of the above equation to be `0` since if we divide `2.5` by `5` the answer will be `0.5` and remainder `0`.

Can you help me understand why this is the behavior or am I mathematically wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mathematically wrong: `2.5` divided by `5` is *not* `5`. It is *`0.5`*. Or, if you are talking about "integer division" (i.e. division where the result is always an integer), the result is `0`. `0 * 2.5` is `0`, therefore, the remainder is `2.5`.

Actually, this is true for *any* pair of numbers `a` and `b` where `b > a` that `a % b == a`.

Comment: Thanks Jörg, it was my bad! it is correct the answer will be 0.5 . what you explained makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

The doc for [Numeric#%](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Numeric.html#method-i-25) states: "`x.modulo(y)` means `x-y*(x/y).floor`". In your example that means:

```
2.5 % 5
  #=> 2.5 - 5*(2.5/5).floor
  #=> 2.5 - 5*(0.5.floor) => 2.5 - 5 * 0 => 0.5
```

Consider four more examples.

```
9 % 2.0
  #=> 9 - 2.0*(9/2.0).floor
  #=> 9 - 2.0*(4.5.floor) => 9 - 2.0*4 => 1.0
9.0 % 2
  #=> 9.0 - 2*(9.0/2).floor
  #=> 9.0 - 2*(4.5.floor) => 9.0 - 2.0*4 => 1.0
9.0 % 2.0
  #=> 9.0 - 2.0*(9.0/2.0).floor
  #=> 9.0 - 2.0*(4.5.floor) => 9.0 - 2.0*4 => 1.0
9 % 2
  #=> 9 - 2*(9/2).floor
  #=> 9 - 2*(4.floor) => 9 - 2*4 => 1
```

The doc for [Float#%](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Float.html#method-i-25) (aka `Float#modulo`) gives two more examples:

```
6543.21 % 137
  #=> 6543.21 - 137*((6543.21/137).floor)
  #=> 6543.21 - 137*(47.76065693430657.floor)
  #=> 6543.21 - 137*47
  #=> 104.21000000000004 
6543.21 % 137.24
  #=> 6543.21 - 137.24*((6543.21/137.24).floor)
  #=> 6543.21 - 137.24*(47.67713494607986.floor)
  #=> 6543.21 - 137.24*47
  #=> 92.92999999999961
```

Answer (score 0):

% - is modulo operator
(In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder after division of one number by another (called the modulus of the operation)
In your case, this is correct:
2.5 % 5 = 2.5

/ - is division
2.5 / 5 = 0.5

As soon as you include one number as float, in this case 2.5, Ruby will automatically convert the result to float even if another number is a string.

I hope this helps,
Augustas

Comment: Thanks Augustas, it is my bad! it is correct the answer will be 0.5 but still the remainder should'nt be 0 ?